# jQuery / DataTables: how to change pagination color

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, pagination

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin (version 1.9.4) and would like to change the color of the pagination.

With CSS I am able to change their background color but I couldnt find a way to change the font color and font hover color for the anchor tags. I would like to change both font color and hover font color for all the below anchor tags to white (#FFFFFF).

**The pagination code looks as follows:**

```
<div id="myTable_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
    <a id="myTable_first" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">First</a>
    <a id="myTable_previous" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
    <span>
        <a class="paginate_active" tabindex="0">1</a>
        <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">2</a>
    </span>
    <a id="myTable_next" class="next paginate_button" tabindex="0">Next</a>
    <a id="myTable_last" class="last paginate_button" tabindex="0">Last</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: inspect each element in browser console , can see all rules that apply and live edit them. Find what works and copy to file

Comment: Thanks - how do i do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you miss the `!important` declaration? In this case it is indeed important.

```css
.paging_full_numbers a.paginate_button {
    color: #fff !important;
}
.paging_full_numbers a.paginate_active {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/CrBkT/

Comment: Awesome - I would never have thought of that and it works. Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 6):

after a bit of messing about this is what i got to work;

```
    .page-item.active .page-link {
        color: #fff !important;
        background-color: #000 !important;
        border-color: #000 !important; 
    }

    .page-link {
        color: #000 !important;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important; 
    }

    .page-link:hover {
        color: #fff !important;
        background-color: #000 !important;
        border-color: #000 !important; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39003/how-to-change-pagination-button-classes):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.classes.sPageButton = 'your class';
```